# Guide to Kubernetes Manifests: Good Resources/Docker Run options

Tags: docker, kubernetes, manifest, kubectl

I was wondering if there was a centralized document on options that are available for use in Kubernetes manifest files;

I know there's a bunch on general YAML files but since theres an overlap of docker run commands and kubectl commands, I wanted to know which ones are actually useable for Kubernetes.

i.e. specifically docker run options include --net=host, --pid=host, --privileged

I know --privileged is for securityContext in the kubernetes manifest
https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/security-context/

```
containers:
...
  -name:
   ...
   securityContext:
     privileged: true
```

but as for the other two I can't find good resources to verify if those options are available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All options and fields are documented within the resource references which you can find in the [Kubernetes reference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/) section.

E.g. for the definition of a [Pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/resources-reference/v1.6/#pod-v1-core) you can check the [related docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/resources-reference/v1.6/#pod-v1-core), you'll find that everything within the "spec" block relates to [PodSpec](https://kubernetes.io/docs/resources-reference/v1.6/#podspec-v1-core) objects and these contain among others Container definitions. Within the [Container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/resources-reference/v1.6/#container-v1-core) reference you'll find all required and optional fields.

I assume that's the centralized document you were looking for.

Besides that you might want to check the [Container Command and Arguments](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/container-command-args/) reference guide.

Comment: Thanks! would I be right in assuming: 

    `spec:
      hostNetwork: true
      hostPID: true
`
are equivalent to --net=hots --pid=host?

Answer (score 0):

The link suggested by @pagid lead to 404s.

The new specifications are detailed under [Kubernetes API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/). Example:

- [POD](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/workload-resources/pod-v1/): `Kubernetes API / Workload Resources / Pod`
- [Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/workload-resources/deployment-v1/): `Kubernetes API / Workload Resources / Deployment`
- [Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/service-resources/service-v1/): `Kubernetes API / Service Resources / Service`
- [Secret](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/config-and-storage-resources/secret-v1/): `Kubernetes API / Config and Storage Resources / Secret`